# $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] Returns a Value of 0

Tags: php, ip

This is an issue that's left me scratching my head.  Most of the time, it returns the IP address fine, but on occasion it logs it as "0" which causes me issues as I am using this for voting.  As you can see in the code below, I switch it over into long form and use the conditional if ip value == 0 then allow to vote.  I have it double protected with 17 hour cookies, but I'd like to solve this issue if I can just to be neat and tidy.  Plus I think there are a few smart folks who clear their cookies and vote multiple times.  Here's the code I'm using:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$iplong = ip2long($ip);

$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ip WHERE ipaddress='$iplong' AND 
url='$urlupdate'");
if(mysql_num_rows($fetch) == 0) {
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ip (url,ipaddress) VALUES ('$urlupdate','$iplong')");
}
$update = "UPDATE pages SET counter = counter +1 WHERE url = '$urlupdate'";
$result = mysql_query($update);
```

Like I said, most of the time this works like a charm, and the cron job clears it up once a day with no issues.  At first I thought it was a noscript issue, but it's triggered through an onclick.  Meaning that code never gets parsed, values don't get inserted, and essentially the link just takes them back to the results page without ever logging info.  I'm so stumped as to what could be causing this!

Comment: It's also possible you're simply seeing multiple users behind NAT. Enforcing one-vote-per-IP really isn't fair for many people.

Comment: meagar, I am aware of this.  It's my understanding that those with dynamic IPs from their providers is a result of this, correct?  I constantly get caught up in IP bans due to this, however the nature of my voting requires me to do so.  It's for forum ranking and other sites who allow these ranking votes only with cookies end up with 1,000 votes a day from a forum with 150 members. lol

Comment: You should limit votes per account. Assuming you have accounts, since you have "members"? NAT and dynamic IPs are completely different. NAT involves many people sharing a public IP address *at the same time*. All the machines in your house will have the same IP on the Internet. In a larger example, all the machines at an office building, or university campus (hundreds of users) may have only one IP. Only one person per university will be allowed to vote in your software.

Comment: No accounts I'm afraid.  Its a site I made to allow similar forums to compete with one another for title of "best."  I don't think anyone would use it if they had to log in.  The cookies have a 17 hour cool down and the IP table gets truncated at midnight every day through a cron job so it's one vote/person/day.  It's not a category large enough to worry about NAT I don't think, but the nature of it makes it ripe for cheating which is done on a similar voting/ranking site.  Anonymous voting will always have the option of cheating, but the multiple filters just makes it more difficult.

Comment: "More" difficult, but still trivial. There are a million ways to hide your IP address, as simple as installing a software package called Tor or visiting one of hundreds of proxy websites out there. One-vote-per-IP is terribly broken. You might say "most of my users aren't going to figure it out", but it literally takes only one single person to figure it out and render the voting useless. Just one person in your user base who gets unlimited votes for their favourite option. Do you think you have at least one smart user?

Comment: I have no doubt they can get around the IP easily.  Hence adding cookies as well.  At least that way they have to proxy up and delete their cookies every time they try to cheat.  It's not much of an added pain, but it's one more button they have to click every time they cheat.  If you have an option I haven't thought of to filter more without requiring folks to sign in, I'm all ears.  That's the goal of this site - an alternative to the others where the numbers aren't as easy to manipulate.  So far the analytics referring sites match the votes pretty closely, so it's working ok so far! =D

Comment: Adding cookies *doesn't* make it harder for that one person though. That one smart person isn't using a browser. They're using a script which completely ignores your cookies to begin with. *That's* what I mean about this being trivial. Cookies are opt-in. Your entire security system is opt-in.

Comment: Okay, I see your point and the loophole.  I'm going to wrap the sql entry queries in an if(isset($_COOKIE()) conditional.  That way if cookies aren't enabled it'll kick out the vote.  That works because the cookie is set when the voting page loads, then the filtering is done in an onclick php page call that sets the url I use to log the IPs and separate the counter values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ip2long in 32bit PHP installs is tricky. For simple MySQL operations, you're better off passing the IP around as a string and using MySQL's native inet_ntoa/inet_aton functions to convert for storage.

```
$ip = mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO ... VALUES (INET_ATON('$ip'));";
```

and then

```
$sql = "SELECT INET_NTOA(ipaddress) AS ip ...";
```

for later retrieval.

Comment: That makes sense, and I originally tried to implement inet_pton (aton is depreciated now that ipv6 is out, right?)  But for some reason I can't get it to parse right.  I'm playing with it now to get the ipv4 to insert right, then I have to enable ipv6 support in my php and see where that goes.  Thanks for the tip!  Now that I know it was probably just the ip2long giving it issues, I have somewhere to start!  I'll let everyone know what I ended up with.  I'll probably end up scripting to check if ipv4 and ipv6 and handle subnets somehow too.